# Material Design (AngularJS) <md-select> not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am trying to use the `<md-select>` tag but I can't have the same result as in [here](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.select).

I am writing this code:

```
<div layout="column" layout-align="center center" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 5px;">
  <h1 class="nomargin">X</h1>
  <p class="unit normagin">milimeter</p>
</div>
<div>
  <md-select ng-model="motion.someVal0">
    <md-option value="1">Move Absolute</md-option>
    <md-option value="2">Move Relative</md-option>
    <md-option value="3">Jog</md-option>
  </md-select>
</div>
```

But the result that I get is this:

[image]

The other Material Design elements is working just fine, only the `<md-select>` tag that seems to not work. I have already tried to read the docs [here](https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.select/directive/mdSelect) but it is so simple that I don't understand why is not working.

When I use the default `<select>` and `<option>` tags it works but I really want to use the Material Design ones.

Comment: What does you console say?

Comment: By console you mean The F12 - Console tab in browser?

If then: 

`GET http://127.0.0.1:49823/bootstrap/bootstrap.css.map 404 (Not Found)`


But I don't think this is relevant because when I use the default `<select>` tag I also get this error.

Comment: Ok no you are right that is not a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've put up this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JowXQy referencing the latest libraries through RawGit, and it's working fine.

I've tried also with the stable ones, from ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ , but the md-select didn't get created. So, it seems to be some kind of libs version problem.

```
<!-- Angulars Material CSS using RawGit to load directly from `bower-material/master` -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
```

```
<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Javascript using RawGit to load directly from `bower-material/master` -->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
```